# Is there a definitive test for an email address backed by gmail?

Tags: gmail

We have a signup flow, we also have login via Google.

The signup flow asks for a password, but if you have an email address managed by gmail, there is no need to pester you to come up with a separate password, when you can just login via Google's OpenID/OAuth2

So I am wondering if there is any quick and easy checks on the email address that allow confirmation that the address is managed by GMail.

It is ok to give false negatives, false positives are completely unacceptable.

Obviously, the "is it @gmail.com" test is a valid one, but I would like something with a lower rate of false negatives.

My next thought is to check the MX records in DNS and see if that is the Google Mail MX record... But is that proof that the account is managed by google?

Or are there any other tests people have?

Comment: Can you show an example for false negative address that ends with `@gmail.com` ?

Comment: There are no false positives for an address ending in `@gmail.com` as they are *all* always managed by gmail. A false negative of the "does the address end in @gmail.com" test is any address ending in `@one-dash.com` as these are all managed by gmail (my domain is using google apps) but the "does the address end in @gmail.com" test says they are not managed by gmail.

Comment: @alfasin, I think you have it backwards. My email address does not end with '@gmail.com' and yet it is hosted by GMail - so would trigger a false negative (i.e. incorrectly deduce I did not have a GMail email) if the '@gmail.com' test was used.

Comment: Oh, now it's clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query for the SMTP server, open a connection to the SMTP server, start sending the email and if you don't get a 550 (user does not exist) then cancel the SMTP session and exit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: BTW, the server will respond with a 250 instead of 550, if the user exists.

Comment: Might such behaviour get me banned/black-listed if we have lots of these though?

Comment: That I do not know my friend.  I have done this on a couple of sites in the past and have not suffered any negative impacts.

Comment: Just curious - how many are you talking about daily?  Understand that SMTP servers are extremely quick and this type of transaction does not at all "tax" the server.

Comment: If we have 1000 per day we'd be over the moon... But the point is that I don't need to validate the email address per se as the users email address is coming via a different 3rd party OpenId/oauth flow, so it's more about saving them from having to create another account. We trust for these people that their email address is valid.... But as a more general question, the smtp test could be abused by others to DoS your signup flow just by forcing many checks

Comment: Apologies, from reading your question, I understood that you were trying to verify the account with Google.

Comment: No, though verification could be seen as a bonus, this is a weaker test. A test of "if this is a valid email (and we don't mind it being invalid) is it managed by google mail". Your answer answers a subset of the yeses. If I get nothing better, I'll award it to you!

Comment: Well, the SMTP protocol offers the VRFY command, which is to verify that the email address is served by the server; therefore, I think it is safe to infer that this is an acceptable transaction.  Also, one can disable the VRFY command on SMTP servers.  Just FYI in case you did not know.

Comment: I guess I could only run the VRFY check on addresses where the DNS's MX record for the domain contains `ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM` or any of the [other Google MX records](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174125). That would reduce the likelyhood of being black-listed by filtering out obvious mis-matches. Accepting this answer on that basis